# Persistent CORS error with laravel 10.19 when initiatitng flutterwave payment

Tags: laravel, cors

I have a laravel 10 project that keeps bringing the errors

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ravemodal-dev.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay/################. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ravemodal-dev.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay/################. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I have read that Laravel 9+ have CORS built in and followed recommended solutions which included

1. adding \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class to kernel.php file
2. editing my cors.php fiile

my cors.php file is

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range'],

    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Origin, Content-Type',

    'exposed_headers' => [
    'Accept',
    'Authorization',
    'Origin',
    'Content-Type',
    'X-Requested-With',
    ],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

I also tried creating my own cors middleware file and adding it to the kernel.php file but the same error has persisted. Is there another way i could resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. The issue had to do with editing my `routes.php` file to add the routes to the payment initiator in the correct middleware group.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).